# Smali toString() not working for given parameter object

Tags: android, smali

I am trying to output a partially unknown object to the logcat (via Log.d), which currently is failing for this method. Failing as in the application crashes without printing the object to the logcat.

Method:

```
.method public a(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/a/a/a/k;Lcom/a/a/a/l;)Lcom/a/a/a/j;
.locals 1

 #!
invoke-virtual {p2}, Ljava/lang/Object;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v0

const-string v1, "#######C0905.m3694#######"

invoke-static {v1, v0}, Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
#!

const/4 v0, 0x0

invoke-virtual {p0, v0, p1, p2, p3}, Lcom/a/a/a/a;->a(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/a/a/a/k;Lcom/a/a/a/l;)Lcom/a/a/a/j;

move-result-object p1

return-object p1
.end method
```

To my knowledge it does inherit from *Object*, therefore *toString()* can be applied. Still very new to Smali, I suppose that I have chosen the wrong registers? Choosing p1 to print the string without the redundant *toString()* works, printing it with *toString()* fails.

Reason:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.a.a.a.a: com.a.a.a.j com.a.a.a.a.a(java.lang.String, com.a.a.a.k, com.a.a.a.l) failed to verify: com.a.a.a.j com.a.a.a.a.a(java.lang.String, com.a.a.a.k, com.a.a.a.l): [0xA] 'this' argument 'Precise Reference: java.lang.String' not instance of 'Reference: com.a.a.a.a' (declaration of 'com.a.a.a.a' appears in /data/app/com.digitalsirup.android.android_endzeitspiel-LZqKD836UaaUhNxKzyt2jA==/base.apk)
```

Comment: "which currently is failing for this method" is not a very useful description of the problem :) How is it failing? Does the log not get printed? Does it crash? If so, what's the stack trace?

Comment: @JesusFreke Pardon me, I have added additional information. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method has 5 registers total, 1 local register, and 4 parameter registers. `v0` is the local register, of course, and `v1`-`v4` are parameter registers, and can also be accessed as `p0`-`p3`. i.e. `v1` is the same as `p0`, `v2` is the same as `p1`, etc.

Just before the call to Log.d, you set v1 to a string. But as I mentioned above, v1 is an alias for p0, so you've just clobbered the `this` reference. And so, when you try to call `Lcom/a/a/a/a;->a(...)Lcom/a/a/a/j;`, the verifier sees that p0 contains a string, not a `Lcom/a/a/a/a;`, and it fails verification.

Comment: This means I have to avoid that registers get overridden, which I solved by moving the code down to the end of the method since `p1` - `p3` remain unchanged. Thanks @JesusFreke, I really appreciate your help and time. Marked as solved, unfortunately I can't upvote yet :)